# XAMPP Control can't connect with MySQL. I tried several things

Tags: mysql, xampp, controlpanel, control-panel

For a school project I need to create a website with Wordpress and I need to have Apache and MySQL started up on the XAMPP Control Panel 3.2.1. I'm running a Windows 7 computer and I don't have any problem starting up Apache, but I do have problems with MySQL. In the panel it gives me this error:

```
11:00:41  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
11:00:41  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
11:00:41  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
11:00:41  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
11:00:41  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
11:00:41  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
11:00:41  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

In the log it says this:

```
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Plugin 'InnoDB' is disabled.
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [ERROR] Aborting
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Binlog end
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-03-13 10:57:26 6380 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete
```

What I've tried:

- Making exceptions or turning off firewalls
- deleting ibdata
- restarting computer
- tried different connections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be dealing with corrupted innodb files and/or disabled innodb engine in your my.ini (which would be weird because it's the default storage engine in current versions).

Try adding to your question the transcript of your my.ini file.

Also, I found a [blogpost of a guy who had a similar problem](http://omarusman.com/blog/tutorials/xampp-innodb-storage-engine-failed-windows8), maybe you should try doing that if you are dealing with a blank database and are not afraid of losing valuable data.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It didn't work at first, but after reinstalling in a new folder and do the steps in the link it finally worked.